# 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, windows, web-services, flask

I am trying to build a movie recommendation system in flask app. But, I am getting the following error:

> BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a
>   request that this server could not understand.

Here is my code.
**app.py**

[image]

**predictor.html**

[image]

**sample.py**

[image]

[image]

**Terminal view**

[image]

**Browser view**

[image]

Comment: Could you show how you are running the server and how you're opening it in browser?

Comment: why would you paste screen capture instead of the actual code?

Comment: Do you get the 400 error upon loading the page, or upon clicking the submit button?

If its the submit button case, then put the `method='get'` in `<form>` tag and see if it works.

Also, submitting a form to the same endpoint can follow something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37212645/6400614

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj  edited the question you can check the terminal and browser view

Comment: Your HTML page has two keys: `movie_input` and `movies`. You only render one of them.

Comment: Also, what does `movie_input` look like? If its not a string then its problematic

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj how am i supposed to change the code? movies is the output we will get

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj it is a string but i amn not able to input anything because of the error

Comment: Ok, found the error: When the page is loaded, there no form and thus the error. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700053/flask-werkzeug-exceptions-badrequestkeyerror

Comment: it worked it allows me to input a string but i am not getting any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if 'movie_input' in request.form:
        movies = similar_movies(request.form['movie_input'])
    else:
        movies = "No movies selected. Please, select something!"
    print(movies)
    return render_template('predictor.html', movie_input=movies)
```

This code will process the situations when no movie_input is provided (like during the first page load)